# Apple Screen Menu Bar with JMenuItem calls actionperformed multiple times

Tags: java, macos

So this is my first question on Stack Overflow so let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. 
Basically in my java app I'm using swing for the windows and menus and then processing for the drawing part. So I have a JMenuBar that has options such as saving and changing tools, etc. When I use the system property apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar to use Apple's built in menu bar at the top of the screen) it calls the actionPerformed method 3 times for a single click. When I stop using this system property (meaning the menu bar is in the JFrame itself) this problem goes away. So my question is how can you use the apple menu bar and not have the actionperformed method called multiple times.

I have done a lot of debugging to isolate this problem and when I looked it up I wasn't able to find the problem. Let me know if specific code would help

Comment: I would try making a limiter or a short cooldown. Basically make it so that after one time of the event firing, run through your handling, and then use a Timer to have a 1-second cooldown or something. Then whilst this timer isn't finished dismiss the event if it's fired again. This is purely theoretical and I'm not even sure it would work.

Comment: That could potentially work i'll try it thanks!